# Running meteor from a checkout

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to run meteor from a checkout following the instructions on the main README: https://github.com/meteor/meteor (under Slow Start.) I'm trying to run the `devel` branch.

When running normal meteor, it starts up a mongo instance using the database stored in the `.meteor` directory of the current project. However, the checked out version throws the following error:

```
W20130729-16:18:46.369(-4)?(STDERR) /home/mao/projects/CrowdMapper/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:184
W20130729-16:18:46.370(-4)?(STDERR) }).run();
W20130729-16:18:46.371(-4)?(STDERR)    ^
W20130729-16:18:46.393(-4)?(STDERR) Error: MONGO_URL must be set in environment
W20130729-16:18:46.395(-4)?(STDERR)     at packages/mongo-livedata/remote_collection_driver.js:32
W20130729-16:18:46.395(-4)?(STDERR)     at _.once (packages/underscore/underscore.js:704)
W20130729-16:18:46.396(-4)?(STDERR)     at new Meteor.Collection (packages/mongo-livedata/collection.js:65)
W20130729-16:18:46.396(-4)?(STDERR)     at packages/service-configuration/service_configuration_common.js:8
W20130729-16:18:46.397(-4)?(STDERR)     at packages/service-configuration.js:42:4
W20130729-16:18:46.397(-4)?(STDERR)     at packages/service-configuration.js:51:3
W20130729-16:18:46.397(-4)?(STDERR)     at mains (/home/mao/projects/CrowdMapper/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:153:10)
W20130729-16:18:46.399(-4)?(STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20130729-16:18:46.400(-4)?(STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/mao/projects/meteor/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20130729-16:18:46.400(-4)?(STDERR)     at /home/mao/projects/CrowdMapper/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:80:5
```

How can I tell this version to use the project-local mongo database and start its own mongo instance as before?

Answer (score 2):

This was caused by a breaking change in the `devel` branch as documented here:

> https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-core/xtTlpFqp4to

This is because Meteor 0.6.5-rc's and later don't automatically include core dependencies that were listed for free before. It can be fixed with

```
meteor add standard-app-packages
```

or

```
meteor run-upgrader app-packages
```